Expanding macro text argument between btex etex
I have created a macro to draw something at a point and apply a label as follows:
def defpoint (expr z)(text side, lab) =
  begingroup
    ... % macro text
    label.side(btex lab etex, z);
  endgroup
enddef;

The idea is that I could call it like so:
defpoint(za)(bot)(A);

and get the label "A" shown.  However, what is produced is "lab", that is, MetaPost seems to reproduce the text between btex and etex verbatim.
Is there any way to fix this behavior?

The tokens between btex and etex are passed to the TeX processor and aren't expanded/interpreted by Metapost.

Thanks.  Are there any known workarounds?

As noted in the comments, btex ... etex are treated as special quotation marks in MP, the contents are treated as written, with no expansion.
But there several ways to "fix" this behaviour and produce what you are trying to do.
Traditional
Look at the way that label is defined in plain.mp and pass the arguments that label is expecting.  So something like this:
vardef gkpoint(expr t, z) = 
   ... your macro stuff ...
   label(t, z);
enddef;

where t is a <string> or a <picture> and z is a <pair>.  The label macro tests the value of t and does the equivalent of this:
draw t if string t: infont defaultfont scaled defaultscale fi shifted z;

(plus some extra logic to do the alignment).
You could also pass your side argument as an optional suffix argument, so that you can pass that onto label as well:
vardef gkpoint@#(expr t, z) = 
   ... your macro stuff ...
   label@#(t, z);
enddef;

Now you can write gkpoint.bot("GK", origin); or gkpoint.top(btex $e=mc^2$ etex, 200 right); or whatever, as required.
Using the TEX macro
Alternatively you could use the TEX macro.  This might be more appropriate if you know you are limited to passing <string> variables to the macro.
input TEX
vardef gkpoint(expr s, z) = 
  ... your macro stuff ...
  label(TEX(s), z);
enddef;

or, with the optional suffix...
input TEX
vardef gkpoint@#(expr s, z) = 
  ... your macro stuff ...
  label@#(TEX(s), z);
enddef;

and now you can write gkpoint.lft("A string label with maths $2+3$", origin); and still have it type set properly.  The only disadvantage of the TEX macro is that it can be a bit slow if you have 100s of labels.  But in that case you should probably switch to using lualatex + luamplib to typeset your MP drawings.  With lualatex you get the TEX macro built-in, and it's very much faster.
For more background and explanations, you might like to read sections 11 and 12 of my guide to Drawing with Metapost.

I was thinking to TEX, but of course you're the main Metapost expert here. Kudos!

There is also the possibility to use the excellent latexmp package and its own 'textext' macro, which is much quicker on the whole than the TEX macro, despite the fact that you'll need to typeset twice to make the labels appear. https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/latexmp/doc/latexmp.pdf

Thank you, went with the vardef macro and that works great!  I do have your guide, of course, and on a careful reading of Ch. 11 and 12 I found a lot of useful information.
